# Mongoose SchemaString#match receiving TypeError

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently attempting to perform schema matching in Node.js using regex and believe that everything is setup according to the proper Mongoose documentation however when I attempted to validate the regex it fails to do so. I am using the following for my Mongoose Schema:

```
var dateTimeMatch = ['/-?[0-9]{4}(-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(-(0[0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])))(T([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9](\.[0-9]+)?(Z|(\+|-)((0[0-9]|1[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]|14:00)))/', 'Deceased DateTime must be in the format: 1992-12-31T23:59:59+14:00'];

module.exports = mongoose.model('Patient', new Schema({
    identifier: [{
        period: {
            start: { type: String, match: dateTimeMatch, required: true},
            end: {type: String, match: dateTimeMatch} //if not ongoing
        }
 }]
});
```

And I am using the following JSON as the payload:

```
{
    "identifier":{
        "period":{
            "start":"1992-12-31T23:59:59+14:00"
        }
    }
}
```

I am attempting to save the model to MongoDB itself using the following code which also seems to be correct.

```
 //Build Mongoose Model for insertion into DB
    var patientBody = new Patient(req.body);
    //patientBody.affiliation = Lookup from UID what company affiliation *TODO
    patientBody.save(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
 }
```

However ultimately I receive the following error:

```
\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\string.js:357
        ? regExp.test(v)
                 ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at EmbeddedDocument.matchValidator (\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\string.js:357:18)
    at \node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:724:28
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:698:19)
    at \node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1191:9
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I believe I have narrowed down the issue to the regex not validating properly, but am unsure as to why or how to proceed any further to correct the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regexp needs to be an actual regexp object and not a string.

Try this:

```
var dateTimeMatch = [
  /-?[0-9]{4}(-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(-(0[0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])))(T([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9](\.[0-9]+)?(Z|(\+|-)((0[0-9]|1[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]|14:00)))/,
  'Deceased DateTime must be in the format: 1992-12-31T23:59:59+14:00'
];
```

Comment: Ah that was it! Thank you so much!